# Using value of a function in other function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

In the code below , I had authenticated the use using passport.js and now I want to use the user variable in other function or file. How can I take this user outside this function?

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('home',{
        name: req.user.username});
```

Comment: Call some outside function inside of the `router.get` callback?

Comment: wanted to use the name : req.user.username by exporting it to other file.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is associated with your `req` object. You can call the other function this way:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res){
   next();
}
PassportFunction(),
AnotherFunctionToAccessUser()
)
```

So, in this, when functionality of `PassportFunction()` will be completed, it will be move to `AnotherFunctionToAccessUser()` which will also be having the access to `req` object, so for the `req.user`.